# javascript unit testing - return different objects from jest virtual mocks

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules

I've a jest unit test which uses a virtual mock.

The virtual mock return an object with apiName = "standard__abc"

I test a function(isApiNameABC()) which uses the mocked object to return true if apiName === "standard__abc" else it returns false.

Using the code below, I'm able to test the condition where true is returned...

My question is, how do I modify my test code so that the virtual mock returns some other value for apiName. I want to do this to test the case where isApiNameABC() returns false.

```
import * as utils from '../utils';

jest.mock('mdl/appContextService', () => {
    return { 
        appContext: {
            apiName: "standard__abc"
        }
    }
}, {virtual: true});

describe("utils", () => { 
    test("test return value of apiName is EQUAL to standard__abc", () => {
        expect(utils.isApiNameABC()).toEqual(true);      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apiName` is just a property on the module export so you can just change it directly.

Assuming `utils.js` looks something like this:

```
import { appContext } from 'mdl/appContextService';

export const isApiNameABC = () => appContext.apiName === 'standard__abc';
```

You can test it like this:

```
import * as utils from './utils';
import { appContext } from 'mdl/appContextService';

jest.mock('mdl/appContextService', () => {
  return {
    appContext: {
      apiName: "standard__abc"
    }
  }
}, { virtual: true });

describe("utils", () => {
  test("test return value of apiName is EQUAL to standard__abc", () => {
    expect(utils.isApiNameABC()).toEqual(true);  // Success!
  });
  test("test return value of apiName is NOT EQUAL to standard__abc", () => {
    const original = appContext.apiName;
    appContext.apiName = 'something else';  // <= change it directly
    expect(utils.isApiNameABC()).toEqual(false);  // Success!
    appContext.apiName = original;  // <= restore it
  });
});
```

---

If `apiName` was a function then you could use a mock function and change its return value:

```
import * as utils from './utils';
import { appContext } from 'mdl/appContextService';

jest.mock('mdl/appContextService', () => {
  return {
    appContext: {
      apiName: jest.fn(() => "standard__abc")  // <= use a mock function
    }
  }
}, { virtual: true });

describe("utils", () => {
  test("test return value of apiName is EQUAL to standard__abc", () => {
    expect(utils.isApiNameABC()).toEqual(true);  // Success!
  });
  test("test return value of apiName is NOT EQUAL to standard__abc", () => {
    appContext.apiName.mockReturnValue('something else');  // <= change the return value
    expect(utils.isApiNameABC()).toEqual(false);  // Success!
  });
});
```